# discord.py Нужно выдать роль пользователю зная его ID

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Мне нужно выдать роль пользователю используя его ID, как я понял мне в любом случае нужно получить объект member, но вот как это сделать имея ID пользователя я так и не могу понять.

Answer (score 3):

вот пример

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions( administrator = True )

async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = 1)

    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = 'MUTE')

    await member.add_roles(mute_role)
    await ctx.send(f'У {member.mention}, ограничение чата, потому что админам так захотелось!')
```